# Free fonts designed for visually impaired people for japanese language?

Tags: discussion

Are there some free fonts to write japanese specifically designed for visually impaired people? Like these ones for the latin alphabet:

- https://www.luciole-vision.com/luciole-en.html
- https://brailleinstitute.org/freefont

If no font was designed for this purpose, which freely available fonts are considered best for visually impaired people?
(maybe something like Arial for the latin alphabet)

Answer (score 3):

[MORISAWA BIZ+](https://www.morisawa.co.jp/products/fonts/bizplus/) **might** be an option, if it meets your criteria of "specifically designed for visually impaired" and "freely available" after reviewing what's written here:

- [Evidence](https://www.morisawa.co.jp/products/fonts/bizplus/study/)
- [MORISAWA BIZ＋ 無償版を利用するにはどうしたらいいですか？](https://support.bizplus.typesquare.com/hc/ja/articles/360000238712)
- [EULA](https://bizplus.typesquare.com/rules/eula)

---

If you could forfeit the **free** requirement, [UDデジタル教科書体](https://www.morisawa.co.jp/topic/upg201802/) is quite reputable.